# Spring Boot RESTful Service with Service and DAO classes having Interface + Implementation layers

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

While developing Spring boot based RESTful web services, why do we need to create Interface + implementation classes for certain layers(service, DAO) rather than just implementation layer link in the below example?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-hibernate4/src/main/java/sample/hibernate4/service

Please consider the requirement here as a web project, which will be packed as a single WAR.

Most of the claims as below says "We change the implementation without much/any impact to the consumer". As long as the method signatures are same(which has to be the case for interface as well), how does it different from just having a implementation?  Even when the implementation changes without impacting the method signature, it would still not effect the caller.

Said that, can someone shed light on why we need interfaces, rather than just implementation classes with some practical example for a Spring REST service project?

[Service and DAO always implement interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477119/service-and-dao-always-implement-interfaces)

Comment: Nothing says you have to have all those interface. It works without but you'll often find that it's useful to have them. Like for testing with mocks.

Comment: I'm not saying its a must to have. I've seen in may examples, including the one mentioned above, which is a official example project from Spring, which has interface+implementation. How it is found useful often? Can you please add some specific examples other than mocking for testing, considering alternate options for testing.

Comment: I'm not sure what more to add other than you'll find in the question you linked and several others, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919108/dependency-injection-proper-use-of-interfaces - ps: the consumer thing is more about swapping implementations to a different class, not adding methods methods.

Comment: To be very specific, in a RESTful service, how would having a interface and implementation for a DAO layer / Service layer help ? responses in those link claim, DAO can be simply replaces when interfaces are there. I would argue same is true when you have just implementation class, as long as signature is same.

Comment: No, you'll have to replace the words `SomeDAOImpl` with `SomeOtherDAOImpl` in your service implementation. Nothing changes when you use the interface. You don't even know the name of the dao implementation in the service. This gets ugly when you have thousands of lines of code that refer to implementations by name.

Comment: If I have to retain old DAO, then yes. If you have multiple implementation for same interface, wont you have to specify which implementations instance you are creating ? In that case, it needs change there as well right?

Comment: Yes, at one place where you configure the beans for the Spring context.

Comment: Also you want to be able to easily switch an implementation to a mock to be able to unit test a service class. Even though there are mock libraries which can mock concrete classes, it is easier if you just have to mock an interface.